# Host-Card Emulation Reader Model

Tags: android, nfc

From reading the HCE developers guide here [HCE Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html) seems it is possible to use an android phone as a reader. I put card information on an NFC tag, and then read it with my phone. I want to have the phone act as the reader. Do you know if this is possible? I have created a sample project with the following lines of code in it:

```
import android.nfc.cardemulation.HostApduService;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MyHostAPDUService extends HostApduService{
@Override
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] apdu, Bundle extras) {
   ...
}
@Override
public void onDeactivated(int reason) {
   ...
}
}
```

I don't know where to go next.

Comment: Do you want to use the phone as a reader or as a card?

Comment: I want to use the phone as a reader please.

Comment: In that case you would want to look into the reader/write mode APIs (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html), look for tag dispatch system and foreground dispatch system). HCE mode is exactly the opposite of what you are looking for. In host card emulation mode, as that name suggests, the phone acts as a contactless smart **card** and not as a reader.

Answer (score -1):

I have achieved using the phone as a reader but through a slightly different approach:

Using an activity as the base I created a simple reader application where I sent a select and then some following APDUs to a card

```
private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
private String[][] mTechLists;
private IsoDep card;

onCreate(){

...

mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

mPendingIntent = pendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),0);

mTechLists = new String[][]{new String[]{IsoDep.class.getName()},new String[]{IsoDep.class.getName()}};


...
}

onPause(){
mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

onResume(){
mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this,mPendingIntent,null,mTechLists);
}

onNewIntent(Intent intent){

Tag theTag = (Tag)intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

card = IsoDep.get(theTag);

...

card.connect();
...
byte[] response = card.transceive(apduBytes);
}
```

I haven't done much more work on this as it was just a proof of concept but I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Hey thanks. This helps a lot. What kind of card did you use? Are you able to send an receive data to/from the card and the phone?

Comment: No probs @Sean! I used a JavaCard running a wallet application. Yes I was was able to send/receive data to it,in this case I was debiting and crediting the balance in the JavaCard wallet applet. All the communications were using APDU's.